# How can I evaluate $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{p^2}{n} \log(n)$?

Tags: calculus, limits

I have an equation like this

$$L=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{p^2}{n} \log(n)$$

Now, if $n$ tends to infinity, does the equation tend to $0$ or Infinity (as the numerator also has a function of n)?

Again, if $n$ and $p^2$ both tend to infinity, what will be the result?

That is
$$L_2=\lim_{n\to\infty, p\to \infty}\frac{p^2}{n} \log(n)$$

How does limit works for a fraction?

Any insight is genuinely appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I have edited my post with the true functions. Please help me to understand the concept. thanks.

Comment: If $\log(n)<n$ as $n\to\infty$, what happens if the denominator tends to infinity faster than the numerator?

Comment: I am a layman in mathematics and reading an article on this field currently. So I am having difficulties to understand this issue.

Comment: Let's consider something simple, $f(n)=\dfrac1n$, what happens as $n\to\infty$?

Comment: Yes it is 0. But then when p also goes to Infinity?

Comment: No I got two condition. 1) when p2 is considered constant. And 2) when it tends to infinity.

Comment: @AwnonBhowmik The inequality $\log(n)<n$ says nothing about the limit of the quotient. The same inequality happens for $n-1 < n$, but its quotient tends to $1$.

Comment: I think log(n)/n tends to 0 as n tends to infinity.  Using L hopital rule i can prove that. But then again, p stays!

Comment: What exactly is $p$? Why does it tend to infinity as $n$ tends to infinity?

Answer (score 4):

The answer depends on what $p$ is exactly . Otherwise, the limit doesn't exist .

Let $n=e^t$ and let $p$ be a function of $t$. Then, the original limit becomes :

$$\lim_{t\to\infty}\frac {t}{e^t}\cdot p^2(t)$$

Take $p(t)=t$ ( or take any polynomial $P_n(t)$ with degree $n$ ) , you get :

$$\lim_{t\to\infty}\frac {t^3}{e^t}=0$$

Then take $p(t)=e^t$, you have :

$$
\begin{align}
\lim_{t\to\infty}\frac {t}{e^t}\cdot e^{2t}&=\lim_{t\to\infty}te^t=\infty \end{align}
$$

Therefore, the answer is *indeterminate* in that sense .

---

I interpreted your second limit as follows :

$$\lim_{(p,n)\to (\infty,\infty)}\frac{p^2}{n} \log n$$

If you take $(n,p)=(e^t,t)$ and $(n,p)=(e^t,e^t)$ as $t\to\infty$, then you have :

$$\lim_{t\to\infty}\frac {t^3}{e^t}=0$$

and

$$
\begin{align}\lim_{t\to\infty}\frac {t}{e^t}\cdot e^{2t}=\infty\end{align}
$$

Therefore, in that sense the above limit does *not* exist .

Comment: The above answer is not an expert answer.  If that's not what the OP was looking for, please note to me in the comments .

Comment: P is not a function of n (i.e., t). And I don't think L2 is undefined. Because where I found this issue, there was nothing about it being undefined. But as far as I guess, maybe they take $L_2 \to \infty$.

Comment: @Dempaty  Well,  How do you define $$\lim_{n\to\infty, p\to \infty}\frac{p^2}{n} \log(n)~~?$$

Answer (score 1):

For the first question, for any fixed $p$

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{p^2}{n} \log n=p^2\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\log n}{n}=0 $$

For the second question, as noticed all depends on how "strongly" $p^2 \to \infty$ with respect to $n$. For example, if for some $0<a<1$

$$\frac{p^2}{n^a} \to 0 \implies \frac{p^2}{n} \log n =\frac{p^2}{n^a}\frac{\log n}{n^{1-a}} \to 0$$

but if

$$\frac{p^2}{n} \to c>0 \implies \frac{p^2}{n} \log n \to \infty$$

therefore we can't conclude anything without any other information.